# Use of "will" vs "willpower"

Tags: word-choice

I got a problem with a sentence, and can't decide which word is the right. I'm writing about my passion (football).

> It is about the qualities, but at most it is about the will.

Is will the right word here?

I am talking about the willpower; the will to win a football game.

I am not really comfortable with English. So be patient please.

Comment: Any word is the right word there, depending on what you want to say. But what is definitely *not* the right word there, is "at most". It makes no sense. You want "most of all", or "first and foremost", or "mostly".

Comment: On a meta note, please use a more descriptive title. "Which word is the right in this sentence" is too generic. It would fit every second question on this site. People don't click on links that say nothing. Describe the actual problem, not its type.

Answer (score 1):

How about *grit* or *hunger*? I think you're trying to [wax a little poetic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wax-poetic), those words would fit nicely if that is what you're trying to do.

*Will* is perfectly correct. One thing you can do with this type of question is to consult a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/will+power).

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to

> It is about the qualities, but **mostly** it is about the will **to win**.

You usually need to add whatever it is that there is a *will* for. It could be the *will to do your best*, *the will to keep going*, *the will to learn* etc. but as it's football it's almost always about winning.

Notice also I have changed *at most* to *mostly*: *at most* normally means *no more than*; *mostly* normally means *the largest portion of something*, or *largest amount of something*

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: You don't need to add something to specify *will*, though it is also correct to do so. Personally, I think the sentence is better with the naked *will*. Adding *to win* draws some emphasis away from *will*, and *will* by itself juxtaposes nicely with *qualities*.